# How to get Weeks as a negative number in JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

This is the current code am working with :

```
 int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(movieReleaseDate, new DateTime()).getWeeks();
```

If the movie was released 8 weeks ago, it gives me the correct output as 8. 
How do I make it return -8 ? To return a negative weeks seems to be the simplest hack which I do not want to do.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Simply do `weeks = -weeks` or change the order of parameters `int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(new DateTime(), movieReleaseDate).getWeeks();` which will give negative value if first parameter is after the second.

Comment: check if movieReleaseDate < new DateTime , if yes then weeks = -weeks

Comment: @michalk Switching the params worked! Can you please turn your comment to an answer so I can accept it ? Or given the now obvious triviality of the question, should I just delete the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply reverse the parameters order:

```
int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(new DateTime(), movieReleaseDate).getWeeks();
```

This will give negative result if the first parameter is after the second one.